# Removing artifacts from binary image with same 'weight' as content

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0, opencv3.1

I'm doing a document edge detection software.
My code works well with the high contrast, smooth background images but now I'm testing it in a complex environment.

For example, image below shows my problem 
[image]

Is it possible, using OpenCV to get rid of the wiggly artifacts and preserve straight document outline for later processing?

I tried, dilation, erosion, opening, closing and other morphological operations, however problem is that artifacts are of same 'weight' as content itself.

Process is:

- resizing image
- doing multiple edge preserving blurs
- canny edge detection
- dilation with 2x2 kernel
- getting contours
- finding polygon with largest surface

Artifact connected to the label is screwing things.
Disconnected artifacts are not a major concern.
[image]

Here is the original image (scaled):
[image]

Comment: Can you add the original image?

Comment: Content updated